# Docker-compose: Database is uninitialized

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I have a problem with docker-compose and mysql:

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2' 
  services:
   db:
    image: mysql
    volumes:
      - "./sito/db/:/var/lib/mysql"
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:

   app:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: eboraas/apache-php
    links:
      - db
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./sito/:/var/www/html/
```

An error occurred when I compose this container:

```
Recreating phpapp_phpapache_1
Attaching to phpapp_db_1, phpapp_phpapache_1
db_1 | error: database is uninitialized and password option is not specified 
db_1 | You need to specify one of MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD, MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD and MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD
phpapache_1 | AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.30.0.3. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
phpapp_db_1 exited with code 1
db_1 | error: database is uninitialized and password option is not specified 
db_1 | You need to specify one of MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD, MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD and MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD
db_1 | error: database is uninitialized and password option is not specified 
db_1 | You need to specify one of MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD, MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD and MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD
db_1 | error: database is uninitialized and password option is not specified 
db_1 | You need to specify one of MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD, MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD and MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD
db_1 | error: database is uninitialized and password option is not specified
```

But the database don't have a password. How can I solve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [docker, MYSQL\_ROOT\_PASSWORD do not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40149880/docker-mysql-root-password-do-not-work)

Answer (score 38):

I just wanted to point out something, if using `docker run` command in terminal and not docker-compose, this would be the command:

```
docker run -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password mysql_image
```

**Just notice** that it won't work if you put `-e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password` after `mysql_image`

Answer (score 26):

According the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#setting-environment-variables-in-containers), instead of `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:` you have to use **-** and **=** and also you should use a 'password'
The result it will be:

`- MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=some_password`

In your example:

```
version: '2' 
  services:
   db:
    image: mysql
    volumes:
      - "./sito/db/:/var/lib/mysql"
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=some_password
```

Answer (score 17):

The problem will appear if you don't specify a value for `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD` (other cases explained below).

You can use one of the following syntax below:

```
# syntax 1
environment:
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: strongrootpassword
```

```
# syntax 2
environment:
 - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=strongrootpassword
```

If you wish to use blank/empty password then use the following:

```
MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=1
```

If you wish to set a random password then use the following:

```
MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD=1
```

Then you can get the generated password using

```
docker logs container_name_or_id
```

In the end you need to specify **ONE** of `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD`, `MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD` and `MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD` according to the entrypoint of MySQL image:

- `-z` is to verify that the variable is not empty

```bash
if [ -z "$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" -a -z "$MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD" -a -z "$MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD" ]; then
    echo >&2 'error: database is uninitialized and password option is not specified '
    echo >&2 '  You need to specify one of MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD, MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD and MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD'
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Hi Mostafa, I couldn't access the generated password using `docker logs <container-id>, how can I access the password?

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you're setting the `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD` to nothing. Per the documentation, it is required.

https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/

> MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
>
> This variable is mandatory and specifies the password that will be set for the MySQL root superuser account.

Comment: great... and how do you do that? `docker run -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root` doesn't work

Comment: It does work. Look at the official documentation. If you run `printenv` in your container you should see the env variables set. https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/

Answer (score 5):

we can use

```
docker container run -d --name mysql -e MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD=password mysql
```

you can give any name and any password

Comment: This is not how `MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD` should be used. it takes `true` or `false` values (defaults to true) in order to generate a random password unless `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD` is set. For more details, you can check the following https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-installation-excerpt/5.7/en/docker-mysql-more-topics.html#docker_var_mysql_random_root_password

Answer (score 4):

just in case someone come here like me

```
docker run --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mysql
```

rest here https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql

Answer (score 1):

You can also add a healthcheck to make sure your db is available before your php app starts

```
db:
image: mysql
container_name: ${MYSQL_SERVER_NAME}
ports:
    - "${MYSQL_LOCALPORT}:${MYSQL_PORT}"
environment:
    - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}"
    - "MYSQL_USER=${MYSQL_USER}"
    - "MYSQL_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_PASSWORD}"
healthcheck:
        test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin" ,"ping", "-h", "${MYSQL_SERVER_NAME}"]
        timeout: 10s
        retries: 10
restart: always
```

And add this in your app :

```
    depends_on: 
    db:
        condition: service_healthy
```

Answer (score 0):

Like mentioned, assign an actual value to the `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD` item in your `environment` section. For a reference to an example I've used before, see here:

https://github.com/alexmacarthur/local-docker-db/blob/master/mysql/docker-compose.yml#L12

If you don't want to store the password in your `docker-compose.yml` file, you can also pass a `.env` file that contains the value, and then have that file ignored in your repo. An example of how that might look is here (using DyanmoDB, but it's the same concept):

https://github.com/alexmacarthur/local-docker-db/blob/master/dynamo/docker-compose.yml#L17

Answer (score 0):

I just specify the password like down below and it works magically. I don't know should I use exist user or not?
MYSQL_USER: root
MYSQL_PASSWORD: 1
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 1

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31341593)