# Connect to MySQL server from php with Docker

Tags: mysql, docker

I am new to Docker. I am developing a PHP application in Docker environment, and I need to use a MySql Server/database to persist data. Following documentation, I run this command to create the MySql server image:

`docker run -v /var/lib/mysql mariadb`

It downloaded it, but I also go this error with it:

> error: database is uninitialized and password option is not specified You need to specify one of MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD, MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD and MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD

How do I set the MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD option?

And then how would I create a database on this image, and then read/write to it from my PHP code (which is on a different image)?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39678463/docker-compose-database-is-uninitialized

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Create container**

Run this command: `docker run --name some-mariadb -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mysecretpw -v mysql:/var/lib/mysql -d mariadb:latest`

With this, you are creating your docker container with mariadb, and storing data on mysql folder. In the command, you have *-e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw*. This set your root password as *my-secret-pw*. When you connect to it, your user is *root*, and password is *my-secret-pw*.

**Find out the address**

`docker inspect some-mariadb` - With this command, you will find all information about your container. You need your IP address.

Hint: `docker inspect some-mariadb | grep IPAddress` you make easier to find your IP Address.

**Connecting**

Now, it is the PHP part. Run the PHP below, but check your host address, that in my case was **172.17.0.2** ([from PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php).):

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("172.17.0.2", "root", "my-secret-pw");

if (!$link) {
    echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}

echo "Success: A proper connection to MySQL was made!" . PHP_EOL;
echo "Host information: " . mysqli_get_host_info($link) . PHP_EOL;

mysqli_close($link);
```

And if works fine, you will read:

```
A proper connection to MySQL was made!
Host information: 172.17.0.2 via TCP/IP
```

Ps.: For database creation, run the required commands as you would make in a database without the docker. It is the same (`CREATE DATABASE mydb`).

This is just for starting. I recommend you to study [docker compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview/). When you get it, will you learn a lot about docker advantages.

Comment: It hangs on this line `$link = mysqli_connect("172.17.0.2", "root", "my-secret-pw");`

Comment: Fixed it, it was because I did not have mysql extension install on the container. For anyone else, I installed it with this command `apt-get install php-mysqli` and then restarted my apache server with `apache2ctl stop` and then `apache2ctl start`