# PHP PDO : SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

Tags: php, mysql, docker, pdo

I ran into this Problem with the PHP Data Object.

I cannot connect to my Database. First here is my PHP Script:

```
<?php

$serverName = "127.0.0.1";
$port = "3306";
$dbName = "callitTime";
$userName = "root";
$password = "superstrongPassword";

try {
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$serverName;dbname=$dbName;port=$port;",
    $userName, $password);

} catch (PDOException $pdoE) {
    echo 'An Error occurred: ' . $pdoE->getMessage();
}
?>
```

I am using:

- PHP 7.1.16
- Nginx 1.13.12-1
- MySQL 8.0.11-1debian9

All as Docker Containers.

A phpinfo() tells me that PDO Drivers are loaded as follows:

PDO Drivers:

- sqlite
- mysql

Driver Versions:

- mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev
- SQLite Library 3.15.1

I get the Error:

```
An Error occurred: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
```

I can connect to the same Database via Phpstorm with the same Password and Username.

Comment: `db-name` should be `dbname`?

Comment: Did you create a user bridge network for your set of containers?

Comment: Yes the Containers are User Bridged! @user188737

Comment: Then I don't understand why you use host=127.0.0.1. Surely the mysql container has a different IP address?

Comment: Never mind I remembered that wrong. @user188737

Comment: From which container did you try phpstorm, or did you try that from the host?

Comment: Phpstorm runs on my host machine and I could connect just via localhost and username and password @user188737

Comment: So you tied the mysql container also to the host network? Does it have two network interfaces?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that this is not a problem related to the PHP Configuration.

The error **`Connection refused`** shows, from my point of view, that you can't establish a connection from the php container to the mysql container.

You need to expose the 3306 Port to the Webserver Container so that the PHP Container can establish a connection to the database. If you already bridged the containers you need to use the containers IP address and not your loopback 127.0.0.1.

> Please see this answer for more information how to connect both containers and how to make a connection from a php to a mysql container: 
>   https://stackoverflow.com/a/43128428/1118905

To narrow down the problem, you can try to establish a connection from within the PHP Container via Netcat to your given DB Host.

For example you can try to establish a connection with the following commands:

> 1. Get into the container from which you want to test the connection. 
>     `docker exec -it <name_of_container> bash`
> 2. Test to open up a connection via netcat (If not all ready available install it via f.e. apt) 
>     `nc -vz 127.0.0.1:3306`

Comment: I´ll give that a try one moment!

Comment: now I´m getting confused I can't even exec into my container ... 2 seconds blank line return to host shell

Comment: You could try with docker attach to get stdin and stdout attached to the running container: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/attach/

Comment: Depending on the answers in your comments on the questions I'm certainly sure, that with the answer in the linked SO Question you can solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are inside container, `127.0.0.1` is not known as a service that hosts the database. You can use the mysql container name instead. For example `$serverName = "mysql";` depending on the name of your container.

sample service definition

```
services:
    mysql:
        image: 'mysql:5.5'
        container_name: mysql
        ports:
            - '33066:3306'
   ...
```

Also note that the port to be used is the internal one.