# Docker-compose up -d - Database is uninitialized (but they are Init.)

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I am having the problem starting up Mysql Container in Docker.

Mysql goes up and than it is constantly in `restart` mode.
[image: The error I got]

The Error message what I got is:

```
[ERROR] [Entrypoint]: Database is uninitialized and password option is not specified
You need to specify one of the following:
- MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
- MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD
- MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD
[Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
[Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.28-1debian10 started.
```

However, 2 of 3 vars are initialized

My `docker-compose.yaml` configration for `Mysql` is:

```
mysql:
        build: ./.docker/mysql
        restart: unless-stopped
        environment:
            - MYSQL_USER=app
            - MYSQL_PASSWORD=123456
            - MYSQL_DATABASE=app
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123456
            - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=true
        volumes:
            - ./.docker/mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql
        networks:
            - app
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"
```

**For those who think that this Post is duplicate.**

I have before this post research other posts (stackoverflow), but it doesnt help me (maybe cos I am using the newest Docker version `Docker Engine => v20.10.8` and those Posts are from 2016)

- [Docker-compose: Database is uninitialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39678463/docker-compose-database-is-uninitialized)
- [docker, MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD do not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40149880/docker-mysql-root-password-do-not-work)

**What did I do until now**

- read `MySql Documentation` about Env vars
- try solutions from [Docker-compose: Database is uninitialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39678463/docker-compose-database-is-uninitialized) and [docker, MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD do not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40149880/docker-mysql-root-password-do-not-work)
- try to remove my existing mysql container and create new one with `docker-compose up -d`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Database initialization happens later than start of other services in docker-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68700807/database-initialization-happens-later-than-start-of-other-services-in-docker-com)

Comment: "*one* of the following". My little fingers count 2.

Comment: If you already have a database in `./.docker/mysql/data`, then it uses that database and doesn't initialize one with the values you've given. Try removing the volume mapping and see if it stays up.

Comment: @HansKilian thx, that was the issue. I have created (before) same image with WSL 2 engine enabled and after I have disabled it that image/volume wasnt visibe. So i had to reactivate WSL 2 and delete old DB. However it works and thank you!